# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'permit_connections=no'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script on a Windows 2008 R2 server to change the contents of an HTM file (Statuspage.htm) from "permit_connections=yes" to "permit_connections=no".  I get the following error:

```
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'permit_connections=no '.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\> ((Get-Content -path D:\inetpub\wwwroot\statuspage.htm -Raw) - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'Get-Content'.
At line:2 char:1
+ PS C:\> Get-Content -Path (D:\inetpub\wwwroot\statuspage.htm)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Following is my script:

```
PS C:\> ((Get-Content -Path D:\inetpub\wwwroot\statuspage.htm -Raw) -replace 'permit_connections=yes','permit_connections=no') | Set-Content -Path D:\inetpub\wwwroot\statuspage.htm
PS C:\> Get-Content -path D:\inetpub\wwwroot\statuspage.htm
```

Comment: The error is not from the code you show. Did you perhaps at one point wrote `Get-Process` where you meant it to be `Get-Content`?

Comment: Remove the PowerShell prompt (`PS C:\>`) from your script.

Comment: `-Raw` is only available on PS 3.0 and newer. 2008 R2 would be PS 2.0 by default. You don't technically need `-Raw` to make this change anyway. Without `-Raw`, however, you may have unintended linefeed/carriage return characters added to your output. You could use `[system.io.file]::ReadAllText(filepath)` instead.

Comment: @Theo no, that threw me off as well.  I never had Get-Process in my script.

Comment: I didn't see it too but @AnsgarWiechers gave the correct answer in his comment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, your comment is the solution - post it below so the question can be closed.  And SoConfused, please make sure to review - tediously - the error messages returned by PowerShell.  They're not just a bunch of red letters, they are actually quite descriptive and helpful if you read them well.

Comment: @Joost It's a typographic error, hence the question should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Gotcha! I didn't know there was a difference on SO.